# How to take the derivative of a function in `Im[]`?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, complex

I tried to take the derivative of a long expression containing $\text{Re} \text{Li}_3(e^{2\pi ix})$, the trilogarithm while $x$ is real. Since the real part function is linear ,it should be like this
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(F(x)+\text{Re}\text{Li}_3(e^{2\pi ix}))=F'(x)-2\pi\text{Im}\text{Li}_3(e^{2\pi ix}))
$$
However, MMA's output is something strange like

```
Derivative[1][F][x] + 
 2 I \[Pi] PolyLog[2, E^(2 I \[Pi] x)] Derivative[1][Im][
   PolyLog[3, E^(2 I \[Pi] x)]]
```

or
$$
F'(x)+2 i \pi  \text{Li}_2\left(e^{2 i \pi  x}\right) \text{Re}'\left(\text{Li}_3\left(e^{2 i \pi  x}\right)\right)
$$
I think the reason is that `D` didn't treat `Re` properly.

How can I let MMA know that `Re` is linear and output the correct result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mathematica  can't figure what to do with or simplify  `Re[PolyLog[3, z]]` nor with `Im[PolyLog[3, z]]` so it just returns `D[Re[PolyLog]]' and `D[Im[....]`  when you apply the derivative operator on these.  What should  `Re[PolyLog[3, ExpToTrig[E^(2 I Pi x)]]` return?  btw, try `D[Im[Sin[x]], x]` and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

We start from the relation $\Re[g'[x]]=(\Re[g[x]])'$ for real values of $x$.
Next, we apply the integral presentation of `PolyLog` (see Details in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolyLog.html?q=PolyLog))
$$\text{Li}_3(\exp (2 \pi  i x))=\int_0^1 \log (t) \log (1-t \exp (2 \pi  i x))/t \, dt $$
Now we differentiate under the integral sign, making use of  [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) . We deal with an improper integral so we should  consider the integral over $[\epsilon,1]$ and then we should  pass to the limit when $\epsilon \to 0+$

```
  Assuming[x \[Element] Reals, D[Integrate[Log[t]*Log[1 - Exp[2*Pi*I*x]*t]/t, {t, 0, 1}], x]]
```

> `2 I \[Pi] PolyLog[2, E^(2 I \[Pi] x)]`

```
  ComplexExpand[Re[%]]
```

> `-2 \[Pi] Im[PolyLog[2, E^(2 I \[Pi] x)]]`

The above result is in accordance with numerical calculations , say for $x=\frac 1 3$.

Edit.The integral representation  $$\text{Li}_3(\exp (2 \pi  i x))= \int_0^1 \frac{\log (t) \log (1-t \exp (2 \pi  i x))}{t} \, dt$$ instead of $$\text{Li}_3(\exp (2 \pi  i x))=-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \log ^2(t) \log (1-t \exp (2 \pi  i x)) \, dt $$